# my java application exited suddenly because of a fatal error {EXCEPTION_UNCAUGHT_CXX_EXCEPTION }

Tags: java, mysql

I have developed a GUI java application. It has login page for user authentication.
It use mysql as back-end. I have wrapped my application using Jar2Exe 1.0 (Regexlab.com) to a 32bit windows .exe file.

not the problem is that when i run the application :

- the database connection is OK;
- the login windows is OK.

When I click on submit button to login into application, most of time, it works and the application continue to work. But sometimes, the application exit without any message and generate a error log which content is as follow:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_UNCAUGHT_CXX_EXCEPTION (0xe06d7363) at pc=0x766fb9bc, pid=8808, tid=7540
#
# JRE version: 6.0_29-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.4-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xb9bc]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0a186000):  JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-10" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7540, stack(0x0e390000,0x0e490000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xe06d7363, ExceptionInformation=0x19930520 0x0e48f41c 0x0042e2c0 

Registers:
EAX=0x0e48f344, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x00000003, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x0e48f344, EBP=0x0e48f394, ESI=0x00429508, EDI=0x0e48f3d4
EIP=0x766fb9bc, EFLAGS=0x00000216

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0e48f344)
0x0e48f344:   e06d7363 00000001 00000000 766fb9bc
0x0e48f354:   00000003 19930520 0e48f41c 0042e2c0
0x0e48f364:   00000008 00000000 0e48f420 00000000
0x0e48f374:   00000000 00000008 0e48f408 00000000
0x0e48f384:   00401dc2 00000000 02448e48 00000000
0x0e48f394:   0e48f3d4 0040df08 e06d7363 00000001
0x0e48f3a4:   00000003 0e48f3c8 02448e60 02448e30
0x0e48f3b4:   e06d7363 00000001 00000000 00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x766fb9bc)
0x766fb99c:   02 50 ff 75 14 8d 45 c4 50 e8 58 ad 02 00 83 c4
0x766fb9ac:   0c eb 03 89 45 c0 8d 45 b0 50 ff 15 5c 11 6f 76
0x766fb9bc:   c9 c2 10 00 cc cc cc cc cc 8b ff 55 8b ec 56 8b
0x766fb9cc:   75 08 83 fe f4 72 18 83 fe f6 77 13 8d 45 08 50 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x0e48f344 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0a186000
EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000003 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ESP=0x0e48f344 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0a186000
EBP=0x0e48f394 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0a186000
ESI=0x00429508 is an unknown value
EDI=0x0e48f3d4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0a186000


Stack: [0x0e390000,0x0e490000],  sp=0x0e48f344,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xb9bc]  RaiseException+0x58
C  [panda.exe+0xdf08]  Java_com_regexlab_j2e_Jar2ExeClassLoader_findResources+0xb528

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.regexlab.j2e.Jar2ExeClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
J  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;
J  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  com.panda.HomePageUI$124.doInBackground()Ljava/lang/Object;+26
j  javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+14
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun()V+30
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+4
j  javax.swing.SwingWorker.run()V+4
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+59
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+28
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0a62b000 JavaThread "Thread-12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8328, stack(0x0f460000,0x0f560000)]
  0x0a62ac00 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1" [_thread_in_Java, id=6056, stack(0x0bdc0000,0x0bec0000)]
  0x0a62a400 JavaThread "Thread-11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4872, stack(0x0bc80000,0x0bd80000)]
  0x0a62a000 JavaThread "Thread-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2980, stack(0x0bb40000,0x0bc40000)]
=>0x0a186000 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-10" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7540, stack(0x0e390000,0x0e490000)]
  0x0a185800 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3852, stack(0x0e250000,0x0e350000)]
  0x0a185400 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5452, stack(0x0e110000,0x0e210000)]
  0x0a184c00 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8800, stack(0x0dfd0000,0x0e0d0000)]
  0x0a184800 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-6" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8740, stack(0x0de90000,0x0df90000)]
  0x0a184000 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4856, stack(0x0dd50000,0x0de50000)]
  0x0a183c00 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=644, stack(0x0dc10000,0x0dd10000)]
  0x0a183400 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=516, stack(0x0dad0000,0x0dbd0000)]
  0x0a182c00 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2772, stack(0x0d990000,0x0da90000)]
  0x0a182800 JavaThread "KeyTipManager processing thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7440, stack(0x0d750000,0x0d850000)]
  0x0a182000 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5576, stack(0x0d500000,0x0d600000)]
  0x0a181c00 JavaThread "SyntheticaAnimation 70" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5660, stack(0x0d400000,0x0d500000)]
  0x0a181400 JavaThread "SyntheticaAnimation 60" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9112, stack(0x0d200000,0x0d300000)]
  0x0a181000 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8860, stack(0x067e0000,0x068e0000)]
  0x0a180800 JavaThread "StreamConnector 1: driver_launched_mysqld_1 std err" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6052, stack(0x09da0000,0x09ea0000)]
  0x0a180000 JavaThread "StreamConnector 0: driver_launched_mysqld_1 std out" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3264, stack(0x09c60000,0x09d60000)]
  0x0a17fc00 JavaThread "driver_launched_mysqld_1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2516, stack(0x09b20000,0x09c20000)]
  0x0a11b000 JavaThread "SyntheticaAnimation 50" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4088, stack(0x0b570000,0x0b670000)]
  0x0023e000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=9132, stack(0x00090000,0x00190000)]
  0x0a11b800 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7784, stack(0x0b430000,0x0b530000)]
  0x0a11e800 JavaThread "D3D Screen Updater" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3808, stack(0x0aef0000,0x0aff0000)]
  0x0a110800 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3828, stack(0x0abf0000,0x0acf0000)]
  0x0a0ac800 JavaThread "SyntheticaCleanerThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8832, stack(0x0aaf0000,0x0abf0000)]
  0x0a05e000 JavaThread "Thread-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8556, stack(0x0a7f0000,0x0a8f0000)]
  0x05b5bc00 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=8968, stack(0x09ef0000,0x09ff0000)]
  0x059c7800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9056, stack(0x066a0000,0x067a0000)]
  0x059c7000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=8364, stack(0x06560000,0x06660000)]
  0x059c4c00 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6100, stack(0x06460000,0x06560000)]
  0x02b11800 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7964, stack(0x053a0000,0x054a0000)]
  0x02afc000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3420, stack(0x05260000,0x05360000)]
  0x02af9000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8732, stack(0x05120000,0x05220000)]
  0x02af5800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8380, stack(0x04fe0000,0x050e0000)]
  0x02aef400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8804, stack(0x04ea0000,0x04fa0000)]
  0x02aedc00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8420, stack(0x04d60000,0x04e60000)]

Other Threads:
  0x02ab1c00 VMThread [stack: 0x04c20000,0x04d20000] [id=7960]
  0x02b25c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x054e0000,0x055e0000] [id=9100]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 78656K, used 59862K [0x24580000, 0x29ad0000, 0x29ad0000)
  eden space 69952K,  73% used [0x24580000, 0x27775a10, 0x289d0000)
  from space 8704K, 100% used [0x289d0000, 0x29250000, 0x29250000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x29250000, 0x29250000, 0x29ad0000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 25650K [0x29ad0000, 0x34580000, 0x34580000)
   the space 174784K,  14% used [0x29ad0000, 0x2b3dc920, 0x2b3dca00, 0x34580000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 11118K [0x34580000, 0x35180000, 0x38580000)
   the space 12288K,  90% used [0x34580000, 0x3505b908, 0x3505ba00, 0x35180000)
    ro space 10240K,  51% used [0x38580000, 0x38aad0b8, 0x38aad200, 0x38f80000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38f80000, 0x39619570, 0x39619600, 0x39b80000)

Code Cache  [0x02b70000, 0x02e78000, 0x04b70000)
....
//----------------------------------------------------------
```

I have googled it. I found some people had the same EXCEPTION_UNCAUGHT_CXX_EXCEPTION problem. Some of them solved their issue changing the thread stack size. I did it to, but I still have the problem.

I would be very happy if anyone can help me, thanks.

NOTE: Panda.exe is the name of application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking over a portion of your error log, and working backwards:

```
1. C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xb9bc]  RaiseException+0x58
2. C  [panda.exe+0xdf08]  Java_com_regexlab_j2e_Jar2ExeClassLoader_findResources+0xb528
3. Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
4. j  com.regexlab.j2e.Jar2ExeClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
5. J  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;
6. J  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
7. v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
8. j  com.panda.HomePageUI$124.doInBackground()Ljava/lang/Object;+26
9. j  javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+14
```

- Line 8: you're clearly in your code when this occurs.
- Lines 7-4: you've moved into Regexlab.com's code; in their classloader
- Lines 2-1: Regexlab's made a native call.  You're outside of the normal JVM code-base, and in native code written by a 3rd party when the exception is raised.  The problem is in Regexlab code, and out of your hands.

Not much you can do with this other than to report it to Regexlab and obtain a patch.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have Panda Antivirus installed on your computer? The log says the problem is outside the JVM, in native code, and there is a reference to a process named 'Panda.exe'.

This is just a guess, but it may be your antivirus conflicting with your application. Can you test your application in a computer without antivirus (e.g. the same Windows installation run as a Virtual Machine)

Comment: Also, check that `panda.exe` process. Googling for it seems to be a virus, NOT part of Panda Antivirus.

Comment: i have tested it in 3 different PCs, with and without antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Give proper permissions to native library that is being used by JVM